# Protocol Error - html-pdf-node npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, server, backend

Using the [htm-pdf-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node) package here. It gives the following error when I am trying to pass the data to it

> Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Invalid parameters
> Failed to deserialize params.url - BINDINGS: mandatory field missing at position 49.

The code I am using is

```
import htmlPdf from 'html-pdf-node';
let option ={ format:"A4",path:"../BoilerplateTemplate"};
htmlPdf.generatePdf(boilerTemp(req.body.Name,req.body.RollNumber,req.body.CollegeName,req.body.Branch,req.body.Batch,req.body.ExperimentNo,req.body.Aim,req.body.Theory,req.body.Procedure,req.body.Apparatus,req.body.Observation,req.body.Conclusion),option)
             .then(pdfBuffer=> console.log(pdfBuffer))
     .catch(error=>console.log(error));
```

The boilerTemp() function has arguments

> (Name,RollNumber,CollegeName,Branch,Batch,ExperimentNo,Aim,Theory,Procedure,Apparatus,Observation,Conclusion)

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc the first parameter of `generatePdf()` should be a file object.

> file <Object> File object should have one of the following properties:
>
> - `url` <string> Any public url of the PDF.
> - `content` <string> HTML file content of the PDF.

Are you sure your `boilerTemp()` function returns that object ?

**EDIT with code in comment**

The code of `boilerTemp()` should be like this :

```
const page = ({ Name,RollNumber,CollegeName,Branch,Batch,ExperimentNo,Aim,Theory,Procedure,Apparatus,Observation,Conclusion }) => {
  let content = ` html template document `;
  return { content };
}

export default page;
```

I changed the parameters with only one object. Like this you can call `boilerTemp()` in a simpler way.

```
htmlPdf.generatePdf(boilerTemp(req.body),option);
```

Comment: const page = (Name,RollNumber,CollegeName,Branch,Batch,ExperimentNo,Aim,Theory,Procedure,Apparatus,Observation,Conclusion)=>{
return ` html template document `} 

export default page;

This is the basic structure of the import.  The return function consists of an Html boilerplate that, with the arguments inserted into it will generate the string that will be converted to the pdf.
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Prakhar I eddited my answer according to your code

Comment: Tried this but no use. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your question with updated code ? and the content of `boilerTemp` ?

Comment: I will surely do it in a day or two. For now, I switched to the html-pdf npm package and it seems to do the job. WIill come back to this after my project is finished. Thanks for your help.